# Error Bound for Euler's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, eulers-method

I'm studying the Euler Method trough the book "Numerical Analysis", but I didn't understand an example where we have to calculate the error of this method...

First of all we have a Corollary which defines the error of this method as follow:

[image]

And here's the example:

[image]

I don't understand why the error bound is $\frac{Mh}{2l} e^L(1 - 0)$ instead of $\frac{Mh}{2l} (e^L - 1)$, because I understood from the example that $a = 0$ and $t_i = 1$ so the $(t_i - a)$ which is in the corollary should be replaced with a $1$ and the answer should be: $\frac{Mh}{2l} (e^L - 1)$

I really don't understand where does the $e^L(1-0)$ come from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a misprint, it should be
$$
e^{L(1-0)}
$$
which is an upper bound for
$$
\left(e^{L(1-0)}-1\right).
$$